# SQL equals does not work for timestamps?

Tags: sql, vertica, dbvisualizer

My table has a category 'timestamp' where the timestamps are formatted 2015-06-22 18:59:59

However, using DBVisualizer Free 9.2.8 and Vertica, when I try to pull up rows by timestamp with a

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp = '2015-06-22 18:59:59';
```

(directly copy-pasting the stamp), nothing comes up. Why is this happening and is there a way around it?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen the question is tagged Vertica.

Comment: From the docs Vertica time stamp has [a resolution of 1 microsecond](https://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/datatype-datetime.html) Is there in fact a decimal part stored that is not shown in your display tool?

Comment: @MinaHan What is the data type of the `timestamp` column?

Comment: @MartinSmith FYI… Regarding [that link to Vertica 5.0 Timestamp doc](https://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/datatype-datetime.html), that data type seems to have changed from that version 5 to [current version 7.1](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/DataTypes/Date-Time/TIMESTAMP.htm?Highlight=timestamp). Previous domain ranged from 4713 BC to 5874897 AD, now 290279 BC to 294277 AD. Same resolution of "1 µs" (or [one microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), for us less mathematically educated).

Answer (score 2):

FYI, saying "the timestamps are formatted 2015-06-22 18:59:59" is incorrect if you are indeed using a TIMESTAMP type. Such types have their own internal representation of a date-time value, almost always a count since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). In your case with Vertica, 8 bytes are used for such storage. The formatting of the date-time value happens *when a string representation is generated*. Never confuse the string representation with the date-time value. Conflating the two may well be related to your problem/confusion.

A few different thoughts about possible problems…

## String Literals

Are you sure Vertica takes strings as timestamp literals? That format you used is common SQL format. But given that Vertica seems to be a specialized database, I would double-check that.

If strings are not allowed, you may need to call some kind of function to transform the string into a date-time values.

## Fractional Second

As the comment by [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) points out, the [doc for Timestamp-related data types in Vertica 7.1](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/DataTypes/Date-Time/TIMESTAMP.htm?Highlight=timestamp) says those types can have a fractional second to resolution of [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond). That means up to 6 decimal places of a fraction.

So if you are searching for "2015-06-22 18:59:59" but the stored value is "2015-06-22 18:59:59.012345", no match on the query.

## Half-Open

The fractional seconds issue described above is often the cause of problems people have when handling a span of time. If you naïvely try to pinpoint the ending time, you are likely to have problems. Seeing the "59:59" in your example string makes me think this applies to you.

The better approach to spans of time is "Half-Open" (or [Half-Closed](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html), whatever) where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Common notation for this is `[)`. In comparison logic this means: `value >= start AND value < stop`. Notice the lack of EQUALS SIGN in the `stop` comparison. In English we would say "look for an hour's worth of invoices starting at 2:00 PM and going up to, but not including, 3:00 PM".

Half-Open for a week means Monday-Monday, for a month the first of one month to the first of the next month, and for a year the January 1 of one year to January 1 of the following year.

Half-Open means *not* using `BETWEEN` in SQL. SQL's `BETWEEN` has [often be criticized](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/160191/34735). Instead do something like the following to look for an hour's worth of invoices. Notice the `Z` on the end of string literal which means "UTC time zone" ("Z" for "Zulu"). (But verify, as my SQL syntax may need fixing.)

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM some_table_
WHERE invoice_received_ >= '2015-06-22 18:00:00Z'
AND invoice_received_ < '2015-06-22 19:00:00Z'
;
```

This query will catch any values such as '2015-06-22 18:59:59.654321" which seems to be eluding you.

## Reserved Word

I hope you have not really named your table 'table' and your column 'timestamp'. Such use of keywords and reserved words can cause explicit errors or more subtle weird problems.

Tip: The easy way to avoid any of the over a thousand reserved words in various databases is to **append a trailing underscore**. The SQL standard explicitly promises to never using a trailing underscore in its reserved words. So use "timestamp_" rather than "timestamp". Another example: "invoice_" table and "received_" column. I recommend doing that as a habit on *everything* your name in SQL: columns, tables, constraints, indexes, and so on.

## Time Zone

You are using the `TIMESTAMP` which is short for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Or so I presume; the Vertica doc is vague but that is the common usage as seen in the [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), and may even be standard SQL.

Anyways, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is usually the wrong type for most business purposes. The `WITH` time zone is misnamed and often misunderstood as a consequence: It means "with respect for time zone" where data inputs that include an offset or other time zone information from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) are adjusted to UTC during the INSERT/UPDATE operations. The `WITHOUT` type simply *ignores* any such offset or time zone information.

The `WITHOUT` type should only be used for the concept of a date-time generally without being tied to any one locality. For example, saying "Christmas this year starts at beginning of December 25, 2015". That means in *any* time zone rather than a specific time zone. Obviously Christmas starts earlier in Paris, for example, than in Montréal.

If you are timestamping legal documents such as invoices, or booking appointments with people across time zones, or scheduling shipments in various localities, you should be using `WITH` time zone type.

So back to your possible problem: Test how Vertica or your client app or your database driver is handling your input string. It may be adjusting time zones as part of the parsing of the string using your client machine’s current default time zone. When sent to the database, that value will not match the stored value if during storage no adjustment to UTC was made.

Tip: Generally best practice is to do all your storage and business logic in UTC, adjusting to local time zones only where expected by user.